# Zipping contents of folder includes parent directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
zip -r $packageName.zip /home/ubuntu/backend/upgrade/temp
```

I expect $packageName.zip to have all the contents in temp folder. However, I'm getting /home/ubuntu/backend/upgrade/contents in my zip folder.

I've tried

```
pushd /home/ubuntu/backend/upgrade/temp
zip -j /home/ubuntu/backend/test.zip ./*
popd
```

and

```
pushd /home/ubuntu/backend/upgrade/temp
zip -r /home/ubuntu/backend/test.zip ./*
popd
```

Comment: Do you have a link from some file below `temp` to `contents`? Otherwise, I don't see how `zip` could possibly reach outside the directory tree which it is supposed to zip.

Comment: Honestly it was operator error type problem. I was using "WinSCP" and the file explorer was showing the path. When I unzipped the folder it dumped the contents only and not the parent directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
zip -rj $packageName.zip /home/ubuntu/backend/upgrade/temp
```

You need the recursive portion of the command combined with the relative paths.